# search data in xml file c#

Tags: c#, xml, search

i am trying search data in xml file. if found, it will popup `MessageBox` and display all the data found.

this is my code.

```
DataView dv;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Documents\\SliceEngine\\SliceEngine\\bin\\Debug\\saya.xml");
        dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
        dv.Sort = "Name";
        int index = dv.Find("Name");
        if (index == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item Not Found");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dv[index]["Name"].ToString()); 
        }
```

but it always said the item not found.

then i tried to do this.

```
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();            
            xml.Load("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Documents\\SliceEngine\\SliceEngine\\bin\\Debug\\saya.xml");
            XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Patient/Patient/Name");
            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                string name = xn["Name"].InnerText;
                listBox21.Items.Add(name);
}
```

for this code, i tried to put it into the listbox. by doing this, it said that it is a null object.

below is my xml file.

```
    <Patient>
       <Patient>
         <Level>0</Level>
         <Name>w</Name>
         <Gender>0</Gender>
      </Patient>
   </Patient>
```

can anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider your code is ok! But here's the problem:

```
xn["Name"].InnerText
```

Becase xn represents `/Patient/Patient/Name` and you just need to do:

```
xn.InnerText
```

to get its value.

Comment: thank you @Diego. it really help. i would voting this high up.

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer to use LINQ to XML like so:

```
// using System.Xml.Linq;

var doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\path\to\file.xml");
foreach (var child in doc.Descendants("Name"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(child.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just getting the childnodes from the **XMLDocument**?

So for example:

```
    // Load up the document
    XmlDocument formXml = new XmlDocument();
    formXml.LoadXml(@"<Patient> 
                      <Patient> 
                        <Level>0</Level> 
                        <Name>w</Name> 
                        <Gender>0</Gender> 
                      </Patient> 
                      </Patient>");


  // get the children nodes from the root
  var children = formXml.ChildNodes;
  // get the first or you can loop through if your xml has more children nodes

  foreach (var child in children)
  {
       listBox21.Items.Add(child.Name); // or something similar
  }
```

Have a look at:

- http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx
- http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/01/08/linq-to-xml-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Unless the xml file has someone called "Name",

'int index = dv.Find("Name");'

should be

'int index = dv.Find("Joe"); //or some other name'